# Cannot get ATOM to retrieve current working directory

Tags: python, directory, atom-editor

I've been programming in Python using ATOM on my MacBookPro for a while. I have the 'Script' package installed so I just use the keyboard shortcut 'command + I' to run the Python scripts within ATOM.

My issue is that the current working directory retrieved in Python is not correct.

```
import os

myPath = os.getcwd()
print(myPath)
```

prints: `/Users/MacBookPro/python_files`

Where as the current directory is actually: `/Users/MacBookPro/python_files/python_programs/deep_learning/pythonprogdotnet/dl_NN_python_pytorch/`

This means I have to create a variable called `absPath` and assign it to the above, then use this variable in my code. Effectively I'm hard-coding the absolute path, but then I have to remove it when I port the code to another machine or a VMS; FloydHub or Colab.

Can someone please inform me how to get the absolute path working in ATOM?

Answer (score 0):

because `getcwd()`(get current working directory) gives you the directory in the terminal that you are running `Python`. 
try this:

```
myPath = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

Comment: I get the following: '/Users/MacBookPro/python_files' when run within ATOM

Comment: @CyberMITZ your python file that contains this code is here?
`/Users/MacBookPro/python_files/python_programs/deep_learning/pythonprogdotnet/dl_NN_python_pytorch/`